# How to turn off pluralize for specific table in Entity Framework 6.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

You can write this code in OnModelCreating method:

modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove();

But this is applying to all tables.
Is it possible to turn off to specific table by passing the table name to such method.

Thnx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().ToTable( "Whatever" );
```

[Entity Mappings using Fluent API](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx)

Comment: Thnx..@SIr Rufo..for quick response..i had created the MapClass in which written that code with fluent api but forgot to add in context configurations ....modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClassNameMap());                                               i accepted your answer.